# Django 3 Form Data not posting to DB and I would like it to, what am I missing?

Tags: python, django

This in in the early stages of testing and my expectation is that I should have enough here to write to the DB and I see no signed of a failure anywhere aside from the empty table after several POST attempts.

#WEB FORM

```
        <form action="/" method="POST" id="ticketsubmitform">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-control" {% if form.date_submitted.errors %}errors{% endif %}>
                {{ form.date_submitted.label_tag }}
                {{ form.date_submitted }}
                {{ form.date_submitted.errors }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-control" {% if form.contact_name.errors %}errors{% endif %}>
                {{ form.contact_name.label_tag }}
                {{ form.contact_name }}
                {{ form.contact_name.errors }}
            </div>
            <div style="padding-bottom: 12pt">
                <button type="submit"> >>> Submit Ticket >>> </button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

#views.py

```
def ticketing_app(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TicketForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            ticket = Ticket(
                date_submitted=form.cleaned_data['date_submitted'], 
                contact_name=form.cleaned_data['contact_name'],

            )
            ticket.save()
    else:
        form = TicketForm()

    return render(request,'authentication/ticketing-app.html',{
        "form": form
    })
```

#forms.py

```
class TicketForm(forms.Form):
    date_submitted = forms.DateField(label="Date Submitted:", 
        required=True,
        error_messages={
            "required": "Date must not be empty."
        
    })
    contact_name = forms.CharField(label="Contact Name:", max_length=45, 
        required=True,
        error_messages={
            "required": "Contact Name must not be empty.",
            "max_length": "Please enter a shorter name."
    })
```

#models.py

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    #---Base Meta-----------------------------------------
    date_submitted = models.DateField(max_length=15)
    contact_name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
```

- No errors on post - [29/Sep/2021 21:18:55] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200
- I do not see anything missing that would prevent a DB write

---

Made change to view: it appears that form.is_valid() is never true.

```
def ticketing_app(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TicketForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            ticket = Ticket.objects.create(
                date_submitted=form.cleaned_data['date_submitted'], 
                contact_name=form.cleaned_data['contact_name'],
            )
            ticket.save()
            print("FORM IS VALID - TICKET OBJECTS:", Ticket.objects.all())
    else:
        print("FORM NOT YET VALID: Awaiting form.is_valid()")
        form = TicketForm()

    # No Issues
    
    return render(request,'authentication/ticketing-instance-usps.html',{
        #"has_error": False
        "form": form
    })
```

```
Even without the validation condition I am still getting a 200 and no record is written. Console output behaves as if it is not processing a POST.

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
[30/Sep/2021 18:24:04] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 3006
[30/Sep/2021 18:24:07] "GET /ticketing/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2815
FORM NOT YET VALID: Awaiting form.is_valid()
[30/Sep/2021 18:24:08] "GET /ticketing-instance/ HTTP/1.1" 200 14230
[30/Sep/2021 18:24:33] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 3006
```

Comment: Try `ticket = Ticket.objects.create(date_submitted=..., contact_name=...)` , and tell us if some errors occur

Comment: No change

[30/Sep/2021 14:22:54] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200

Comment: When you print `Ticket.objects.all()` in the views. What is the result ?

Comment: Made change to view: it appears that form.is_valid() is never true nor is the POST detected as such despite console output. If I remove the else: for if request.method = = 'POST' it results in an error.

Answer (score 1):

You have `GET /ticketing/` and `POST /` - you are posting the form to a different URL.

To resubmit the form to the same URL, change the form tag to one of the following:

```
# Submit to the same URL
<form action="." method="POST" id="ticketsubmitform">

# Hardcode the URL
<form action="/ticketing/" method="POST" id="ticketsubmitform">

# Use the URL tag - you will need to change this depending on your URL pattern names
<form action="{% url 'ticketing' %}" method="POST" id="ticketsubmitform">
```